# How to find CDF of $|X-Y|$ when X and Y uniformly distributed in a coordinate triangle?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, uniform-distribution

Let $XY$ be two uniformly distributed random variables indicating a coordinate on a triangle $T ∶ ((0,1), (1,0), (0, −1))$, how to find both cumulative and probability density function of $|X − Y|$.

**My solution to the problem**

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFtZ0.png)

If $Z = |X-Y|$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
F(z) &= P{(|X-Y|\le z)} = P(Y\le X-z)\cup P(Y\ge X+z) \\
&= 1-z \text{ (Given the area formula in above linked figure)} \\
%&= \int_0^{\frac{1+z}{2}}\int_{x-z}^{x+z}dydx = \int_{0}^{\frac{1+z}{2}}2zdx \\
%&= z+z^2 \\
P(z) &= \frac{d}{dz}F(z)\\
&= -z
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Please give your thoughts on the problem so that we know what you've done so far and where you're having difficulty.

Comment: I added my approach, I just finished it. I'm not sure of the solution.

Comment: Thanks, close vote retracted. Also, though it's probably discernible from your attempt, can you say whether the triangle $T$ is a solid triangle or just the outline? (I assumed outline when I first saw the problem, but now I'm fairly sure it's solid.)

Comment: It is a solid triangle.

Comment: That is the correct shaded area but you computed the wrong one... you want $z,$ not $1-z.$